# Domain depending on host might load or not without www

Tags: domain-name-system, ssl

I'm doing an analysis for this domain nelson.com and I found that when I try to get that url (without www.) I get an error.

But, somehow, when my partner does the same, it loads correctly redirecting to [www.nelson.com](http://www.nelson.com)

On the other hand, I've also found that they're having major issues with their SSL certificates.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Online tools "DNSViz" and "Qualys Server SSL test" could be your first 2 stops to get detailed information. You will find DNS errors that needs first to be attended to: https://dnsviz.net/d/nelsom.com/X8f1bQ/dnssec/ and "SSL" errors: " Warning: Inconsistent server configuration ". So there is some amount of work to be done here.

Comment: `www.nelson.com` is a CNAME to an Amazon AWS hostname. `nelcon.com` has hard-coded IP addresses (you can't put a CNAME at the domain apex), they look like other Amazon addresses.